# QNetworkAccessManager HTTP Put request not working

Tags: qt, http, networking, put, qnetworkaccessmanager

After an exhaustive search on the web about this issue, none of the answers found solved it.

Using the technology Qt_5_15_2_MSVC2019_64/Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler,
I'm trying to send a JSON file through HTTP put request from QNetworkAccessManager to a custom QTcpServer, but when doing so, only HTTP headers are received (even twice) but not the JSON file in itself.

Snippet Code:

```
void Sender::putParameters(const QString& p_parameters)  {
   QJsonDocument docJson = QJsonDocument::fromJson(p_parameters.toUtf8());
   QByteArray data = docJson.toJson();
   QUrl url= QUrl("http://127.0.0.1:80/api/devices/1285/parameters");
   QNetworkAccessManager* nam = new QNetworkAccessManager(this); // Even tried to put as member variable but still did not work

   QNetworkRequest networkReq(url);
   networkReq.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/json");
   networkReq.setRawHeader("Content-Length", QByteArray::number(data.size()));
   
   QObject::connect(nam, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, this, 
   &Sender::validateParameters);
   nam->put(networkReq, data);

   if(docJson.isEmpty())
      qDebug() << "JSON was empty";
}
```

Result QTcpServer:
[image]

With Poco library there's no issue it works, or sending HTTP put request via Postman it does work.

Comment: Could you share the code for your QTcpServer that is printing the result you have pictured? Wondering if you're perhaps not correctly retrieving the data for the request on the receipt side.

Comment: What is the purpose of parsing the json from a UTF-8 string into a `QJsonDocument` and right after that serializing it back into a UTF-8 encoded byte array? If you intended to check the validity of input json string then you don't actually do it: `QJsoDocument::fromJson` returns null `QJsonDocument` if parsing fails but you don't check it via calling `QJsonDocument::isNull()`. It might be that your input json is invalid and hence serializing null `QJsonDocument` produces an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

@dabbler

Sorry for the late answer but here is the code snippet of the Server :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQ923.png)

With postMan and Poco it's working perfectly, so I don't know if the issue is then related to the server, and for the client side @Dmitry you're right I should use QJsonDocument::isNull instead (but I used isEmpty() just for demonstration purpose that I wasn't sending an invalid Json which is not the case, the json is valid).

Comment: If you are posting answers please use code and use the format option. Screenshot of code is no use as users cant copy/paste or run it for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Yes my bad @Syfer
So I have the class Server inheriting from QTcpServer and overriding function incomingConnection such as : `void incomingConnection(qintptr) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;`

Here is the code snippet:

```
Server::Server(QObject* parent) : QTcpServer(parent) 
{
    if(listen(QHostAddress::Any, 80))
        qDebug() << "Ok listening port 80";
    else 
        qCritical() << "Fail listening";
}

void Server::incomingConnection(qintptr p_intPtrSocket)
{
    QTcpSocket* socketClient = new QTcpSocket(this);
    socketClient->setSocketDescriptor(p_intPtrSocket);
        
    connect(socketClient, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(onReadyRead()));
}

void Server::onReadyRead()
{
    QTcpSocket* socketClient = (QTcpSocket*)sender();
    QString fullClientRequest = QString::fromUtf8(socketClient->readAll());
    QStringList clientReq = fullClientRequest.split("\n");
        
    qDebug() << "client response: " << clientReq;
 }
```